CSS: Problem in the navbar, due to the position of the text selection rectangle and the drop-down menu
I'm creating a navbar but I have a problem when I move the mouse over an item (for example on Company) to display the drop-down menu below.

The problem is that the green selection rectangle is positioned too close to "Company" (almost as if to underline it), instead I would like to position the green rectangle much lower and precisely on the lower edge of the navbar. Consequently I would also like to improve the drop-down menu because it seems to be positioned too much above and overlapping the navbar. The result I would like to obtain is this:

I think the problem is related to:

padding and margin of the navbar;
padding and margin of the navbar items (maybe they conflict)
line-height;

or maybe the problem is something else, i don't know, i can't solve it.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item.dropdown");

    dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
        dropdown.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
            const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
            if (menu) menu.style.display = "flex";
        });

        dropdown.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
            const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
            if (menu) menu.style.display = "none";
        });
    });
});
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* Navbar */
.navbar {
    background-color: #000033;
    padding: 0px 0; /* Imposta il padding verticale invece dell'altezza */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

/* Stile logo e testo del brand */
.logo {
    height: 80px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.brand-text {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1;
}

.fondazione {
    font-size: 0.80em;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.28em;
}

.surname {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

/* Rettangolino colorato sotto le voci della navbar */
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px; /* Gestisce lo spazio tra i link */
    line-height: normal; /* Usa la line-height di default */
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px; /* Altezza del rettangolo */
    background-color: #459439;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* Allineato al bordo inferiore */
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

/* Rimozione della freccia dropdown */
.nav-link.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}

/* Dropdown orizzontale */
.dropdown-menu-horizontal {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000033 !important;
    padding: 20px !important;
    min-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal:hover {
    color: #d4d4ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Mostra il menu a tendina al passaggio del mouse */
.nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/* Responsive per dispositivi mobili */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>


<!-- Navbar con logo e link -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark mb-0">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
            <img src="img/..." alt="Logo" class="logo">
            <div class="brand-text">
                <span class="fondazione">AAAAAAA</span>
                <span class="surname">XXXX</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="fondazioneDropdown">COMPANY</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-horizontal" aria-labelledby="fondazioneDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 1"> Example 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 2"> Example 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 3"> Example 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 6</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 7</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



Thank you

Can you convert your code into a snippet?

@LajosArpad Some kind user converted the code into a snippet. I also leave you the JSFiddle link I was writing you: https://jsfiddle.net/9afboq74/1/

I think you could wrap a div around your links and change your rules to .navbar-nav > li > div and .navbar-nav > li > div:hover::after, respectively, with height: 100%;.

@LajosArpad First I saw your answer with the solution, then maybe you deleted it. I noticed that it didn't work properly, that's not what I wanted. Could you show it to me again please? (but correct). Thanks

I have written an answer that looked good on a certain screen size and then it did not fare well on other screen sizes. I removed it indeed. I might take another look later on, but not now.

The idea is to use the total height for the nav links on the right. Here are the steps to do it:

Add align-items-stretch class to the container to stretch the items of the container vertically to utilize the full height for the nav links
Add h-100 class to the ul element so that it gets 100% height of it's parent
Set the 100% height to the nav-link as well and then align vertically using Flexbox

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


Add align-self-center class to the navbar-toggler button so that it doesn't stretch vertically like other items

Dropdown positioning:


.dropdown-menu-horizontal {
    top: 97% !important;
}


Overriding the padding for Navbar: (In some places it is showing some padding. I don't know why)

.navbar {
    padding: 0 !important;
}



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item.dropdown");

dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
    dropdown.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
        const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
        if (menu) menu.style.display = "flex";
    });

    dropdown.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
        const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
        if (menu) menu.style.display = "none";
    });
});
});
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* Navbar */
.navbar {
    background-color: #000033;
    padding: 0 !important; /* Imposta il padding verticale invece dell'altezza */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Stile logo e testo del brand */
.logo {
    height: 80px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.brand-text {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1;
}

.fondazione {
    font-size: 0.80em;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.28em;
}

.surname {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

/* Rettangolino colorato sotto le voci della navbar */
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px; /* Gestisce lo spazio tra i link */
    line-height: normal; /* Usa la line-height di default */
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px; /* Altezza del rettangolo */
    background-color: #459439;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* Allineato al bordo inferiore */
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

/* Rimozione della freccia dropdown */
.nav-link.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}

/* Dropdown orizzontale */
.dropdown-menu-horizontal {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000033 !important;
    padding: 20px !important;
    min-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 97% !important;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal:hover {
    color: #d4d4ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Mostra il menu a tendina al passaggio del mouse */
.nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/* Responsive per dispositivi mobili */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>


<!-- Navbar con logo e link -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark mb-0">
    <div class="container align-items-stretch">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
            <img src="img/..." alt="Logo" class="logo">
            <div class="brand-text">
                <span class="fondazione">AAAAAAA</span>
                <span class="surname">XXXX</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto h-100">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="fondazioneDropdown">COMPANY</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-horizontal" aria-labelledby="fondazioneDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 1"> Example 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 2"> Example 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 3"> Example 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 6</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 7</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



